# How do I automate a cloudformation.json (or yaml) file stored in codecommit to auto deploy via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

From what I can tell, if I create a buildspec.yaml, I can run it through codepipeline with a codebuild to run the cloud formation.  However, to do this requires spinning up an ec2 to the execute the cli to cloudformaiton (I guess that's how it's working under the covers).  This seems like overkill to just run a cloudformation, and although using the console might be faster in this case then waiting for the ec2 to launch, there must be an easier way?  Am I missing something?

I thought maybe I could just go straight from codecommit to deploy, but getting the template file into an s3 bucket seems the missing step here.

Is there an easier way, or "This is the way?"

Answer (score 0):

You can [deploy a CloudFormation template via a Deploy action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/integrations-action-type.html#integrations-deploy-CloudFormation) from CodePipeline, see the screenshot below. In this case, you won't need a CodeBuild action at all.

[image]

As an alternative, you can also pass on CodePipeline completely and use a [trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-notify-lambda.html) + [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/deploy-cloudformation-stacks-at-the-click-of-a-button/) function instead. I wouldn't recommend that though as as you're essentially building your own custom CI/CI engine then, so you'll not have the usual out-of-the-box features available such as easily adding additional steps, doing manual approvals, etc. - instead, you will have to build this on your own when required.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I guess I'm just surprised AWS doesn't have a serverless solution for something that seems so basic and rudimentary for a cloud. It feels like cloud 101 to me.  At work we were all bamboo, so I didn't have to worry about it. I like your idea of lambda, and I think codepipeline integrates with lambda, so maybe the workflow could still work.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: Lambda is what you'd typically use for any serverless compute, but as you're essentially just trying to deploy a CloudFormation stack, I've double checked what options there are and you can indeed deploy a template directly via CodePipeline. I've adjusted my original answer with the updated findings. Hope that solves the problem to your satisfaction.